# remove lines that are a subset of previous lines in a huge file using map-reduce

Tags: python, mapreduce

I have a huge flat file (no data base), with fixed number of columns ( 4 columns).

```
London  Londres Londen Londra
London    NA    Londen  NA
  NA      NA    Londen  NA
```

Where NA represents blank entries. The goal is to remove the lines that provide no extra information (lines 2,3). In other words these lines are a subset of the first line. Is there a map-reduce approach to detect  lines 2,3 as subsets of line 1 and remove them?